# Haskell type alias defeated by error "qualified name in binding position"

Tags: haskell, type-alias

As a Haskell newbie, I am trying to use the keyword 'data' to define a type alias. This is my simple whole file:

```
import qualified Data.Array.Unboxed
data Point = Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray Int Double
```

GHC says "Qualified name in binding position: Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray"

Why can I not use a qualified name?
How should I define my type-alias then?

Comment: use `type Point = Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray Int Double` ;)

Comment: For type aliases use `type`, not `data`.

Comment: OMG how could I miss this!

Comment: Please someone close this stupid question of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using the `type` keyword, which declares a type alias.  The `data` keyword declares a new, custom data type.  So you could do something like

```
data Point = MkPoint (Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray Int Double)
--           ^ The constructor name
```

But you seem to only want

```
type Point = Data.Array.Unboxed.UArray Int Double
--           ^ No custom constructor for type alias
```